# Find the smallest natural number $k$ such that $f^k(0) = 0$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a,b$ be natural numbers with $1 \leq a \leq b,$ and $M = \left[\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right]$. Define the function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ by $$f(n) = \begin{cases}n+a, \quad &\text{if } n < M,\\n-b, \quad &\text{if }n \geq M .\end{cases}$$ Let $f^1(n) = f(n), f^{i+1}(n) = f(f^i(n)), i = 1,2,\ldots .$ Find the smallest natural number $k$ such that $f^k(0) = 0$.

Why in the solution below do they say "Clearly, it suffices to consider the case $\gcd(a,b) = 1$"? How did they generalize at the end to get $\dfrac{a+b}{\gcd(a,b)}$?

**Solution:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If $\gcd(a,b)=d$, then $f^{i}(0)$ will always be a multiple of $d$. In other words, it suffices to consider the restriction of $f$ to  $d\Bbb Z$, and then identify $d\Bbb Z$ with $\Bbb Z$. 
The only problem is the floor function in the definition of $M$. However, the precise definition of $M$ doesn't matter anyway - all wee need is that $0\in S$, i.e., that $M-b\le 0\le M+a-1$.